# How to combine $elemMatch with a regex

Tags: php, mongodb

The following filter

```
['labels' => [
    '$elemMatch' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex(
        '/^' . preg_quote($this->_keywords[$i]) . '$/i'
    )
]]
```

applied to the function below

```
public static function readDB(
    $collectionName, 
    $filter, 
    $options
) {
    //logError("readDB filter:", $filter);
    try {
        $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager(
            "mongodb://localhost:27017"
        );
        $rqt = new MongoDB\Driver\Query(
            $filter, 
            $options
        );
        $results = $manager->executeQuery(
            "leibnizdream." . $collectionName, 
            $rqt
        );
        return PhysicalAccessors::objectToArray(
            $results
        );
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        logError($e->getMessage());
        return array(
            "error" => self::MSG_KO . $collectionName
        );
    }
}
```

results in the following error:

```
$elemMatch needs an Object
```

My log reports this:

```
[$elemMatch] => MongoDB\BSON\Regex Object(
    [pattern] => /^ad$/i
    [flags] => 
)
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax ? I didn't manage to find it on internet.

KR
Zlotz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) has examples. $elemMatch requires an operator, you can use [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex) to perform a regular expression match.